# C# VS2010 and Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

Hi within my app I've a CR that is set up to create an email when a field is clicked. This functionality is working in preview mode of the report but when I actually run my application and get to the report the functionality is not working. Though when I hold my mouse over the field I can see the mailto formula that I've created appear as a tooltip. Any ideas why this is not working when my app is running?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ReportViewer control? What is the HyperlinkTarget property set to? I think you probably want it to be _blank

Comment: thanks for the reply but I think this was actually bug in CR for VS2010, I ended up uninstalling the version I had an installing an earlier version and it works now